# git over webdav http-push-failed error

Tags: git

I'm trying to set up git via WebDAV, the idea is to host it on my NAS where I cannot install any software, so I can't really use smarter transports.

Now clone works, but push does not: I get "http-push-failed" with the error code 22 - I googled that and all I found is that I have to enable webdav to allow for pushing but it is already enabled(I can mount it on windows and then work on it, but I would prefer to push directly to it).

I did run git update-server-info and I'm trying it in a local network.

The command I tried is

```
git push http://username:password@domain/share/.git master
```

(I also tried https)

Answer (score 0):

Once you've done git update-server-info you need to restart apache with service apache2 restart.

If you continue having the same error edit the file .git/config into your client repository and modify the "url" line of [remote "origin"] like this:

```
url = http://username:password@domain/and/repository.git
```

If this doesn't resolve the problem it's probably it will be a wrong permission's set in the folder you have your repository or your project. All the files (include the project's file like project1.git) should have the owner www-data (eg: chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/repository)

This three tips solved my problem.